# How do you further check the action type after ofType?

Tags: react-redux, redux-observable

I have an epic that listens to two action types, just call them setSomething and setSomethingFast. For the these actions I'd like to use debounceTime with a certain value. The question is how can I tell which action type it is currently, so that I can set the debounce amount accordingly? The ofType operator returns an Observable here, so I can't use it in there.

```
export const postSomethingEpic = (
  action$: ActionsObservable<PayloadAction<Something[]>>,
  state$: StateObservable<RootState>
): Observable<any> =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(setSomething.type, setSomethingFast.type),
    debounceTime(**action$.ofType(##setSomethingFast##)** ? 0 : 2500), <-- How can I tell which action here is which?
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to come up with a workaround. So I created two epics instead, postSomethingEpic with debounceTime and postSomethingFastEpic that doesn't have debounce. The normal epic will emit the setSomethingFast action with the payload being passed through. Would still be interested to know if there's a shorter way to do this.